# iOS: programatically determine if WiFi connection is 2,4Ghz or 5Ghz

Tags: ios, objective-c

I´m developing an iOS App using Texas Instruments Launchpad CC3200. But the awesome SmartConfig feature is only working for 2,4Ghz WiFi Network connections. 
Users trying to do SmartConfig on hybrid or 5Ghz only WiFi connections are failing.

Does anybody know if it is possible to programmatically determine what type of WiFi connection (2,4Ghz or 5Ghz) an iOS device currently has?

Comment: ref this link of stack exchange [answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73719/how-can-i-tell-which-band-2-4ghz-or-5ghz-my-iphones-wifi-connection-is-on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible unless your device is jailbroken or if you have access to private headers in the API.

The only thing you can do is tell the difference between cellular and WiFi connection using the [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) class by Apple. The networking tools are very limited in this case.